# How to pause programmatic execution inside a DispatchQueue without using sleep()

Tags: ios, swift, post, timer, sleep

so I make a post request to a server. In the response, I run some code in the main thread and conditionally call another post request. My problem is this--I need to wait ~5 seconds before the conditional is processed. How can I do this without using sleep()? (Using sleep freezes my app).

```
func getStuff() {
    let server = appState.server + "extension"
    let package = self.myID
            
    guard let url  = URL(string: server) else { return }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(package) else { return }
            
    urlRequest.httpBody = data

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else { return }
        let jsonData = Data(dataString.utf8)
        var decodedJob: Job? = nil
        do {
            decodedJob = try JSONDecoder().decode(Formatter.self, from: jsonData)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.firstTimeLoading = false
                sleep(5) //how do I replicate this behavior without freezing the app?
                if array == [] {
                    otherPostFunction()
                }
            }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Use sleep?  What good does it inflect on your app?

Comment: Ask not what `sleep()` can do for you.  Ask what you can do for the asynchronous process.

Comment: @ElTomato sleep freezes the app for the amount of time passed in--I just need some kind of programmatic delay. I was thinking about using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter inside of this outer DispatchQueue, but that didn't work--not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I've already made a suggesting for what you need.  I would ask Google, Yahoo! or whatever about it if I were you.

Comment: @ElTomato Do you mean use async/await? I can't do that because I'm not working in Swift 5.5.

Comment: Nope.  I've never said that.

Comment: @nickcoding2 have a look at the documentation for DispatchQueue, there are other functions than plain old `async(execute...` if you would like to do something _after_ a given time...

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(5)) {[weak self] in
            if self?.array ?? [] == [] {
                self?.otherPostFunction()
            }
}
```